# External Monitor Resolution Only Available On Extend Display But Changes When Lid Is Closed

Tags: laptop, windows-8.1, display, multiple-monitors, resolution

I have an Acer Aspire E11 laptop and I am running Windows 8.1 with an older Gateway 17" monitor as a secondary display.

My objective is to use the laptop essentially as a desktop while at home with just the 17" monitor running. The resolution of the external monitor is `1280x720`. I am able to select that resolution for the monitor only when I select to extend the monitor.

When the laptop is open the resolution is perfect. When I close the lid the resolution changes to `1024x768` which doesn't look very good. The laptop monitor resolution remains native and nice.

How do I keep the resolution of the external monitor from changing when I close the lid on the laptop?

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out for anyone who might have the same issue later on. I set the second monitor to the primary display, then after closing the lid on the laptop and having the resolution changed I simply right clicked on the desktop and changed the resolution. Now the screen keeps its native resolution after closing the lid.